# what do colon and & statements mean in js module export lines mean?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

In the react native github is this line:

```
module.exports=((Animated: any) : (typeof AnimatedImplementation) & typeof Animated);
```

what does it mean? & and :
these are type hints or something?

Answer (score 3):

Those are https://flow.org/ type annotations. You can tell the file uses Flow syntax by the header comment having a `@flow` marker.

Comment: in the meantime, since I don't have time to read another documentation at this moment can you just explain what is being returned on this line?

Comment: That's a bit arrogant, isn't it? You didn't even link the file where this code appeared; I already took the time to look that up.

Comment: I'm in my car watching a video while waiting in line driving. It's a bit hard. when to doc is text in a video that I reproduced.

Comment: The particular syntaxes at play here are https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/ + https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/ so now you don't need to look through all the docs.